# Kohana auth module returns null, while using Auth::instance()->login

Tags: php, kohana

I am trying to use the Auth module with ORM driver in Kohana 3.3.0, but the only thing I can do is insert new users in the database. I can't login with them.

```
                $user = ORM::factory('User')->create_user($user_data, array(
                'username',
                'password')
            );
            $user->save();
            $user_id = !empty($user->id) ? $user->id : 0;
            $user_type = !empty($_POST['admintype'] ? $_POST['admintype'] : 3);
            //$user->add('roles', ORM::factory('Role', array('name' => 'login')));
            $user->add('roles', $user_type);
```

user is created but when i try to login it returns null

```
            $user_name =  !empty($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
        $userpassword = !empty($_POST['userpassword']) ? ($_POST['userpassword']) : '';           

        $user = Auth::instance()->login($user_name, $userpassword);
```

Comment: Please provide your code where you are getting this error so we can diagnose the problem.

Comment: thanks code added in question body. @RyanNerd

Comment: check the password is encrypted or not...

Comment: bbfcde02189e21be35c50a716744c7df8c64853a1fc1320b3e5abd2c9179eeff
password in database

Comment: What are the values of `$user_name` and `$userpassword` **before** this `$user = Auth::instance()->login($user_name, $userpassword);` is executed? Perhaps these data points are null or invalid??

Comment: username: 31345678932
Password: 12345678
before
`Auth::instance()->login()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Auth->login()` [returns login status](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Auth_ORM#_login), so it should be:

```
$auth = Auth::instance();
if($auth->login($user_name, $userpassword)) {
  $user = $auth->get_user()
} else {
  throw HTTP_Exception::factory('403', 'Login fail');
}
```

And better use native kohana functions to [get values form arrays](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Arr#get):

```
$user_name =  Arr::get($_POST,'username','');
```

or in controller [use](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/Request#post):

```
$user_name =  $this->request->post('username','')
```